# how to append in a specific line in file in python 3?

Tags: python, file, python-3.4

I am making a program for my computer science assignment. I need to make a quiz for 3 classes in a primary school. Then the results have to be saved in a file. I've done the program till here but the next task asks me to let each student have 3 turns and give an average for each one.
here is the code I used to save the results into a text file:

```
def savetofile():
    result = result ="\n "+ namestudent.get() + "          "fscore.get()+"/4"
    messagebox.showinfo("results", "your results been saved successfuly")
    if int(year.get())==1:
        f = open('results C1.txt', 'a')
        f.write(result)
        f.close()
    if int(year.get())==2:
        f = open('results C2.txt', 'a')
        f.write(result)
        f.close()
    if int(year.get())==3:
        f = open('results C3.txt', 'a')
        f.write(result)
        f.close()
```

how can I check if the new user taking the quiz has already done the quiz or not and how can I add the new results of that person in front of their name also how can I take the average of their 3 sets of score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, you output `your results been saved successfully` before writing to a file, which is not true, because the file writing can fail and thus not end up done successfully.

Then you do open and close your file in the following way:

```
    f = open('results C1.txt', 'a')
    f.write(result)
    f.close()
```

which is wrong as well because if the write fails for any reason (like an exception reading the result variable), the file won't be closed properly, and the output may not get flushed to it.

You should instead do:

```
    with open('results C1.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(result)
```

which will take care of opening, flushing and closing the file correctly.

Then the following line is wrong:

```
result = result ="\n "+ namestudent.get() + "          "fscore.get()+"/4"
```

as it misses a `+` between the spaces and the score result. You'd better write something like (with the `\n` at the end to avoid having an empty first line):

```
result = "{}          {}/4\n".format(namestudent.get(), fscore.get())
```

> how can I check if the new user taking the quiz has already done the quiz or not?

To do it you need to do the following algorithm:

```
# to open the file:
with open('results C1.txt', 'r') as results:
    # read the file
    for result in results:
        # split the line
        name, score = result.split("          ")
        if name == namestudent.get():
            # do something when the student exists
```

> how can I add the new results of that person in front of their name also how can I take the average of their 3 sets of score?

Then my suggestion for this is to not work directly with the files, but instead open up a "cache" dictionary of all the scores:

```
def load_scores():
    years_tuple_default = (None, None, None) # create a tuple with as many entries as there can be years
    student_scores = dict()
    with open('results C1.txt', 'r') as results:
        # read the file
        for result in results:
            # split the line
            name, score = result.split("          ")
            student_scores.setdefault(name, years_tuple_default)[0] = score

    with open('results C2.txt', 'r') as results:
        # read the file
        for result in results:
            # split the line
            name, score = result.split("          ")
            student_scores.setdefault(name, years_tuple_default)[1] = score

    with open('results C3.txt', 'r') as results:
        # read the file
        for result in results:
            # split the line
            name, score = result.split("          ")
            student_scores.setdefault(name, years_tuple_default)[2] = score

    return student_scores
```

Then, create a function save the cache into the files:

```
def save_scores(student_scores):
    with open('results C1.txt', 'w') as results_y1:
        with open('results C2.txt', 'w') as results_y2:
            with open('results C3.txt', 'w') as results_y3:
                for student, scores in student_scores:
                    results_y1.write("{}          {}/4\n".format(student, scores[0]))
                    results_y2.write("{}          {}/4\n".format(student, scores[1]))
                    results_y3.write("{}          {}/4\n".format(student, scores[2]))
                print("Results saved!")
```

And finally, work against that cache:

```
def update_scores(student_scores, namestudent, fscore, year):
    if namestudent.get() not in student_scores.keys():
        # add the student entry
        student_scores.setdefault(namestudent.get(), (None, None, None))[int(year.get())-1] = fscore.get()
    else:
        # update the student year entry
        student_scores[int(year.get())-1] = fscore.get()
```

which would end up with a code looking like that to put it all together:

```
student_scores = load_scores()

# do your stuff to get the namestudent/fscore/year data

update_scores(student_scores, namestudent, fscore, year)

# when all updates are done, you can alter the files

save_scores(student_scores)
```

### To sum up:

- split your algorithm into functions,
- protect your file handling using the `with` statement
- read the files once to create a "cache" to work against, and save the result at once when you're done

---

### Bonus ideas

#### use a class

From there, to get further, you could create a class, and have all that as methods:

```
class StudentScores:
    def __init__(self):
        self._student_scores = dict()
    def load_scores(self):
        # TODO
    def save_scores(self):
        # TODO
    def update_score(self):
        # TODO
```

And then calculating the mean of the scores is simple stupid, it's just adding a method to the class which prototype would look like:

```
class StudentScores:
    …
    def get_mean_scores(self, student):
        score_y1, score_y2, score_y3 = self._student_scores[student]
        score = # calculate the average of the three score
        return score
```

#### use a with statement

And if you want to shine, you could implement it as working with the [`with` statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm):

```
class StudentScores:
    def __init__(self):
        self._student_scores = dict()
    def load_scores(self):
        # TODO
    def save_scores(self):
        # TODO
    def update_score(self):
        # TODO
    def __enter__(self):
        self.load_scores()
        return self
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.save_scores()
```

And then your code would like that:

```
with StudentScores() as student_scores:
    # do your stuff to get the namestudent/fscore/year data
    update_scores(student_scores, namestudent, fscore, year)
```

---

To conclude, I'm showing you how I'd design something to do your assignment, whereas I'm not trying to *do* your assignment on your behalf. My goal here is to help you get ideas and learn something about software design and python. Some things may be above your current level (like how to create a with statement), but as you're learning, you'll be able to fully understand and apply everything I'm telling you here.

HTH